# Is it correct to use merge functionality to load data from statging tables to dimensions and facts in BigQuery DWH?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

I am working on a BigQuery DWH project, currently we are loading data from staging to dims/facts using MERGE(since most of the data loads are SCD type1) and hashing all columns to check if hashvalue is new or changed. It is working fine and for each query it is consuming like 30GB for processing 60-70 Million rows. there are close to 30 merge queries. Is this a right way to load data? we are not using any third party data integration tools. Kindly share any tips/experience.

Thanks!

Comment: In order to properly address your question can you provide more information about your process? Such as, how are you loading your data to BigQuery ( from GCS, locally ..)? After loading, do you use merge to update/insert/delete data and what for ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AlexandreMoraes We are using dataflow to read data from ERP source and loading into BIGQUERY staging dataset tables. Now, using merge queries we are loading data from staging dataset tables to presentation dataset tables(Dimension and fact table). Merge queries were only for update and Insert, if the row is found to be new it'll be inserted and if changed then updates. This insertion/update is based on hash comparison from source to target tables.

Comment: thanks for your response. I see that you are using one of the recommended ways of loading data into BigQuery, using Dataflow, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#dataflow). Then with MERGE you guarantee that your data is consistent and complete. Thus, your process is accurate.